# Flutter make touch events pass through AppBar

Tags: flutter, dart

Need my transparent AppBar to allow touch events to fall through, but not for the drawer navigation button.I want the user to be able to scroll the list no matter if they are at the top of the device screen. If you run the code below the AppBar prevents the touchDown while the finger is on the appBar.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final appTitle = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
      appBar: AppBar( title:Text(title), elevation: 0.0, backgroundColor: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.0)),
      body: Center(child: ListView(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[600],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[500],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[100],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[600],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[500],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[100],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[600],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[500],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[100],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[600],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[500],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[100],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[600],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[500],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[100],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[600],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[500],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[100],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[600],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[500],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[100],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
    ),
  ],
)),
      drawer: Drawer(
        // Add a ListView to the drawer. This ensures the user can scroll
        // through the options in the drawer if there isn't enough vertical
        // space to fit everything.
        child: ListView(
          // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text('Drawer Header'),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Item 1'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Item 2'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assumed you don't want the AppBar, that's why you made it transparent; Not sure tho.

But if you don't want it and you still want the Drawer Menu Button at the top left then you can use a `Stack` to achieve this

Like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final appTitle = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: ListView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.amber[600],
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.amber[500],
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.amber[100],
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.amber[600],
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.amber[500],
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.amber[100],
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.amber[600],
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.amber[500],
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.amber[100],
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.amber[600],
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.amber[500],
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.amber[100],
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.amber[600],
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.amber[500],
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.amber[100],
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.amber[600],
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.amber[500],
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.amber[100],
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.amber[600],
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.amber[500],
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.amber[100],
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 10,
            child: Builder(
              builder: (context) {
                return IconButton(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                  onPressed: (){
                    Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
                  },
                );
              }
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        // Add a ListView to the drawer. This ensures the user can scroll
        // through the options in the drawer if there isn't enough vertical
        // space to fit everything.
        child: ListView(
          // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text('Drawer Header'),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Item 1'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Item 2'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```